# Best solution for online video classes?

Tags: video

If I want to make a website where visitors can sign up to online video classes, which of the following options is the best solution?

1-) All the students meet the teacher(me) with TeamViewer (which is a free and easy to get software).

2-) Use some online service like justin.tv, BlogTv etc and have a private room for my students.

3-) Buy a video stream host service and implement some video application on my website. (With this one I'll have to worry about people hacking my website and watching the classes without my knowledge).

Even though I'm a PHP/MySQL programmer, I'm planning on using my website just so people can sign up. For the online video classes, I think using third party services is best/safer.

Which of these is the best solution, taking into consideration security and control over who's watching my classes (should only be those I allow), and also that this isn't a big thing so I don't have many students (less than 50 so far) so a very complex application wouldn't be necessary at the moment.

Or is there a even better solution?

ps: sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this question

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend you two steps in achieving your goals.
For Live Classes

First make a simple website with an E-Mail Subscription area where users can opt-in for your classes. Now you can email them when classes are going to be held. For the Live classes use GoToMeeting.

For Non-Live Classes
Use a Vimeo Pro Account, as it is preferred over the default YouTube player and upload all your videos. Now embed them on your website. I think vimeo is perfect as per your requests.

If you need any other help, do let me know.

Comment: Hey Rahul. I have some questions regarding GoToMeeting. I know I could simply go to their support service but they're just gonna tell me it's the hottest new thing. Is the screen resolution good? Can the viewers read what I'm typing on my screen (it's important since its going to be programming classes)?

Comment: dude, the screen resolution of GoTo Meeting is one of the best on the web. As far as what your student reads also depends on their internet connection. Anything above 1Mbps Internet Speed should produce crystal clear text.